# Pod Install throwing error in terminal for Xcode project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoa pods into my project, so followed installation of pod file setup. So, latest pods installed to my system.

When I tried to install pod file to my project throwing following error.

But, pod file create with blank.

I have given following command and getting following error :

```
MacBook-Pro:Videos username$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client projects
[!] Could not automatically select an Xcode workspace. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

    workspace 'path/to/Workspace.xcworkspace'
```

And I tried Pod init also, if I try to open pod file, its showing empty pod file. And not even showing Target which is default pod file setup.

Anyone suggest me, how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: There is a difference between installing pod and installing pod file. Pod file is installed (better use initialised) by pod init

Comment: I have tried both, but, its creating empty pod file which is blank file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general approach while installing pod. Make sure you follow these and it should work fine (I am assuming cocoa pods are installed on your system) So your issue lies in one of the following steps:

> 1. Go to the project root directory - cd root_directory_path
> 2. pod init
> 3. Open pod file and add required pods (See library installation guide. Each has one)
> 4. pod install

Empty pod does not get created usually. But even if it does, you can just copy the format of pod file contents into your file and install the pod.
As to your empty pod file, reinstall cocoa pods on your system. Also make sure pod is uninstalled from project/workspace you are working on. There might be a faulty installation earlier.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: After I uninstall pods completely and then reinstalled, then again created new project, then reinstalled pod file to project. Its working now. I thought without reinstall pods there may be some solution for this issue, anyway thanks to your suggestions. Worked for me. your suggestions

Comment: Perfect. Good luck ahead !!

Comment: Hi @Nitish, Can you check this once, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767081/after-installed-framework-from-pods-not-able-to-import-in-class-in-swift-projec

Comment: Sure. Let me check