# After installed framework from pods, not able to import in class in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have installed some framework by pod file in my Xcode project. I am using Xcode 9.2. Its installed successfully, but, while trying to import that third party framework to my main class, showing no such module found.

Even tried so many times complete clean and rebuild. But, still showing the error **No such module found** OR **Cannot load underlying module for XLPagerTabStrip**.

In framework search paths it's showing like below PFA.

[image]

Comment: import ur pod file and clean ur project

Comment: tried, but, still same issue.

Comment: try to re-install

Comment: thats also done, but no use.

Comment: i had a similar issue. For me this worked: 
Clean project - Close Xcode - restart Mac - open Xcode - Clean project 
i did not expect the restart to have any impact, but it did. Did you try a restart?

Comment: Yep tried restart, nothing helped.

Comment: tell the pod file name

Comment: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip#provide-information-to-show-in-each-indicator

Comment: @Anilkumar iOS developer did you installed latest version of that pod ?

Comment: yep, I installed latest pods today.

Comment: Include this in ur framework searchpaths "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/XLPagerTabStrip"

Comment: It is working for me

Comment: Cannot load underlying module for 'XLPagerTabStrip' showing error

Comment: Xcode version??

Comment: Xcode 9.2 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165053/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-suganya-marlin).

Answer (score 5):

If you face `No such module found XLPagerTabStrip`, then:

**1)** Click on your app name on side of a select simulator for a run and click on the manage scheme.
**2)** Try to find XLPagerTabStrip And checked it and close it.
**3)** Then click on the app name where you can see XLPagerTabStrip.
**4)** Then click on it then clean build project and again choose your app and then again clean and build.

[image: Here]

where you have to click in the screenshot. you can find `Demo`

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things you can follow :

> 1. Clean project + Remove derive data and build again.
> 2. Check the Pods project on Xcode and make sure your pod exists in the Pod folder under Pod project.
> 3. Add the Pod in Embedded Framework in project settings.
> 4. Edit your scheme :
>      Scheme menu > Manage Schemes > check Pods > Close
>      Select Pods from the scheme menu.
>      Build Pods.
>      Select your project from the same menu, then build/run it.
> 5. Reinstall Pod :
>      pod deintegrate
>      pod install
> 6. Make sure you are correctly setting the pod in Pod file. Refer to original Github page of the library for the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

First clean your code
right after pod installation is complete, build it once. Don't import pod files till now.
After build is succeeded now you will be able to import pod files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to

General -> Linked FrameWorks and Libraries

Click on plus button  and search your installed pod(installed as framework, if UserFrameWork! is mentioned in podFile) and press Add.